# Counting permutation of Strings

Tags: algorithm

I need help with a problem. Given an input string with repetitions, say "aab", how to
count the number of distinct permutations of that string.
One formula that could be used is n!/n1!n2!.....nr!.

However calculating these ni's takes time O(rn) and O(n),if we
use a lookup table.

However I need a solution without use of such tables.Is any recursive or
dynamic programming solution possible for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldn't it be simply n! (if n is the lenght of your string)?

Comment: @MRalwasser: That will only work if all the characters are distinct. The OP's formula is correct when repeated characters are allowed. For example, `"aaa"` has 1 distinct permutation, not 3!.

Comment: I believe recursive or dynamic programming solutions will take more space than this lookup table, the length of which can be bounded by the minimum of the size of alphabet and the length of the string. The only suggestion is that cancel the common factors of the numerator and denominator as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

no. of distinct permutations will be `n!/(c1!*c2*..*cn!)`
here `n` is length of the string

`ck` denotes the no. of occurence of each distinct character.

> For eg: string :aabb n=4 ca=2,cb=2
>   solution=4!/(2!*2!)=6

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this for very large strings, consider using the gamma function (with gamma(n+1)=n!), which is faster for large n and still gives you floating-point accuracy even in cases where you would get an int overflow.

If you have arbitrary precision arithmetic, you could probably push the effort down to O(r+n) by exploiting the fact that you can, e.g. write 1*2*3 * 1*2*3*4 * 1*2*3*4*5*6*7 as (1*2*3)^3 * 4^2 * 6*7. The end result will still have O(rn) digits and you'll still have an O(rn) time consumption, because multiplication cost increases with the size of the number.

I don't see the difference between lookup tables and dynamic programming - basically, dynamic programming uses a lookup table that you build on-the-fly. (i.e., use a lookup table, but only populate it on-demand).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need approximate answers, or exact ones?  Which part of this calculation do you think is slow?

If you need approximate answers, use the gamma function as @Yannick Versley suggested.

If you need exact answers, here is how I'd do it.  I'd first figure out the prime factorization of the answer, then multiply those factors out.  This avoids division.  The hard part of figuring out the prime factorization is figuring out the prime factorization of `n!`.  For that you can use a trick.  Suppose that `p` is a prime, and `k` is the integer part of `n/p'.  Then the number of times that`p`divides`n!`is`k`plus the number of times that`p`divides`k`.  Proceed recursively and it is quick to see that, for instance, the number of times that`3`is a factor of`80!`is`26 + 8 + 2 = 36`.  So after you find the primes up to 'n', it isn't hard to find the prime factorization of 'n!'.

Once you know the prime factorization, you can multiply it out.  You expect to be dealing with large numbers, so try to arrange to do lots of small multiplications first, and only a few big ones.  Here is a simple way to do that.

Make an array of the prime factors.  Scramble it (to mix up big and small factors).  Then as long as you have at least 2 factors in your array grab the first two, multiply them, push them onto the end.  When you have one number left, that is your answer.

This should be much, much faster for large strings than the naive approach of multiplying the numbers one at a time.  However in the end you will have very large numbers, and nothing can make multiplying those fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a running counts for each character, and build the result up as you go along. It's impossible to do better than O(n), since without looking at every character in the string you can't know how many of each character there are.

I've written some code in Python, with some simple unit tests. The code carefully avoids large intermediate values when the result is going to be small (in fact, the variable `result` is never larger than len(s) times the final result). If you were going to code this up in another language, say C, then you might use an array of size 256 rather than the defaultdict.

If you want an exact result, then I don't think you can do better than this.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def permutations(s):
    seen = defaultdict(int)
    for c in s:
        seen[c] +=  1
    result = 1
    n = 0
    for k, count in seen.iteritems():
        for j in xrange(count):
            n += 1
            result *= n
            result //= j + 1
    return result

test_cases = [
    ('abc', 6),
    ('aab', 3),
    ('abcd', 24),
    ('aabb', 6),
    ('aaaaa', 1),
    ('a', 1)]
for s, want in test_cases:
    got = permutations(s)
    if got != want:
        print 'permutations(%s) = %s want %s' % (s, got, want)
```

Answer (score -1):

As @MRalwasser says, the number of permutations should be *n*!.  You can [generate those](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Algorithms_to_generate_permutations) permutations fairly simply, but the run time is going to be exponential because you have to hit exponentially many output strings.  (Quick way to show O(*n*!) = O(2<sup>n</sup>) is by using [Stirling's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).)

Comment: We're only counting distinct permutations, so e.g. the string "aab"  has only three ("aab", "aba", "baa"), not 6

Comment: Then you should have made it clear that you were talking about an input string with repetitions. I've edited the question.

Comment: Stirling's approximation is more O(n^n) than O(2^n) - given a finite set of characters, however, you are indeed limited to exponentially many.